# Get the few letter of word in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking get few letters in a string of words. So it should be first 5 characters (if there are more than 5 if not then the whole word and the subsequent first characters of the next words 5+1(+1...)

E.g. Key Account Sales
I would like to get just "KeyAS"
or HR General - HRG

I am currently using this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFirsties5]
(
    @str NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE retval NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET str=RTRIM(LTRIM(@str));
    SET retval=LEFT(@str,5);

    WHILE CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1) > 0 BEGIN
        SET str=LTRIM(RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1)));
        SET retval+=LEFT(@str,1);
    END

    RETURN retval;
END –
```

but this gives a result as "Key AAS" or "HR GeG"

Few more things to note

> Version - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) -
> 10.50.6560.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:03:48   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build
> 6002: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)

Currently what I get

```
Empl ID Name    Job Family           Description
123 John Smith  Key AAS              Key Account Sales
124 karen Smith HR GeG               HR General
213 John Doe    Production Operator  Production Operator
```

What I expect

```
Empl ID Name    Job Family       Description
123 John Smith  Key AS           Key Account Sales
124 karen Smith HR G             HR General
213 John Doe    ProduO           Production Operator
```

Code that I am currently using is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFirsties5] ( @str NVARCHAR(4000) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET @str=RTRIM(LTRIM(@str));
    SET @retval=LEFT(@str,5);

    WHILE CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1)>0 BEGIN
        SET @str=LTRIM(RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1)));
        SET @retval+=LEFT(@str,1);
    END

    RETURN @retval;
END
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected result if there are 6 (or more) words?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be achieved in a single query. Are you open to using procedures/functions?

Comment: What is the real world purpose of this? It is a very strange requirement and I can't come up with any idea where this would be needed.

Comment: Open to fuctions,

I am using a function currently which was from this forum its called [fnFirsties] 

Edited to capture 5 characters

Comment: ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFirsties5] ( @str NVARCHAR(4000) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE retval NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET str=RTRIM(LTRIM(@str));
    SET retval=LEFT(@str,5);

    WHILE CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1)>0 BEGIN
        SET str=LTRIM(RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(' ',@str,1)));
        SET retval+=LEFT(@str,1);
    END

    RETURN retval;
END

Comment: [Edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: we are importing some data over to a DW and they need unique values for some job descriptions

The only way is to go first 5 characters if the word is more than 5 and 1 word from each subsequent characters

If the first word is more than 5 characters than we only need the first i.e. Production Operator should return ProduO

Comment: Just a note we are still on SQL 2008, in process to move to new versions.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Is this just a one time thing to import this data to your DW?

Comment: This will be a job that will be scheduled for daily import into the DW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirements

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable Values
 ('Key Account Sales')
,('HR General')
,('Customer Support Group')

Select SomeCol
      ,NewValue = concat( left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'),5)
                         ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'),1)
                         ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'),1)
                         ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]'),1)
                         ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]'),1)
                         ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]'),1)
                         ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[6]'),1) -- Expand if more than 7 words
                        )
  From @YourTable A
  Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                 NewValue
Key Account Sales       KeyAS
HR General              HRG
Customer Support Group  CustoSG
```

EDIT - If you'd rather a function

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[YourFunction] (@S varchar(150))
Returns varchar(50)
Begin
    Return (
            Select concat( left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'),5)
                          ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'),1)
                          ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'),1)
                          ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]'),1)
                          ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]'),1)
                          ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]'),1)
                          ,left(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[6]'),1) -- Expand if more than 7 words
                           )
             From (values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(@S,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ) ) A(S)
           )
End
```

**Usage**

```
Select [dbo].[YourFunction]('Key Account Sales')
```

**EDIT--- 2008 XML Version**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[YourFunction] (@S varchar(150))
Returns varchar(50)
Begin
    Return (
            Select coalesce(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(5)'),'')
                  +coalesce(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(1)'),'')
                  +coalesce(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(1)'),'')
                  +coalesce(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(1)'),'')
                  +coalesce(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(1)'),'')
                  +coalesce(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(1)'),'')
                  +coalesce(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(1)'),'')
             From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
           )
End
```

**Usage**

```
Select [dbo].[YourFunction]('Key Account Sales')
```

Comment: The function is a good option but I guess, syntax's like concat, JSON_VALUES, string_escape are not in 2008 SQL server

Comment: @Vicky  Ooof!  2008... give me a moment for a 2008 version

Comment: @Vicky See updated answer.  I added and XML version

Comment: Hi John, I plused you and borrow your `from(values(` for my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can mostly pull this off using `STRING_SPLIT()` functionality. This is sketchy though since `STRING_SPLIT()` doesn't output the ordinal of the term that is being split. That being said, we can sort-of fake it with `CHARINDEX()`. But realize that ordinal will fail in the event that the same word is repeated in your input string. This may still provide a path forward for you though:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (s1 VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('This Is A Test');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('And Another Test');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('Key Account Sales');

SELECT
  s1, 
  SUBSTRING(STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(value, 1, 5) ELSE SUBSTRING(value, 1, 1) END, ''), 1, 5) as output
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      s1,  
      value,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1 ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value, s1, 1)) as rn  
    FROM t1
      CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s1, ' ')
  ) sub
GROUP BY s1

+-------------------+--------+
|        s1         | output |
+-------------------+--------+
| And Another Test  | AndAT  |
| Key Account Sales | KeyAS  |
| This Is A Test    | ThisI  |
+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: The ordinal seems like a missed opportunity by MS   +1

Comment: I couldn't agree more @JohnCappelletti. It's a disappointing miss for sure.

Comment: @JNevill - have you seen that MS added the ordinal position recently? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Of course it still has a swing and a miss that it doesn't return a NULL if the inbound value is NULL.

Comment: The OP is on SQL 2008 R2. In any case, the ordinal support is only available on Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only).

Answer (score 1):

One more very *elastic* approach running on v2008 (which you *really* should upgrade...)

--Some test values in a declared table variable

```
DECLARE @input TABLE(YourString VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('Key Account Sales')
                        ,('HR General')
                        ,('Production Operator')
                        ,('') --test edge cases
                        ,(NULL)
                        ,('a b c d e f g')
                        ,('Some incredibly long and stupid text to test even this');
```

--the query (borrowed the `FROM(VALUES(` from John's answer)

```
SELECT xDim.query(N'(
                     <itm>{substring(concat((/x[@pos=1]/text())[1]," "),1,5)}</itm>
                    ,for $rest in /x[empty(@pos)]
                     return
                        <itm>{substring(($rest/text())[1],1,1)}</itm>
                    )
                   ').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @input i
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CAST('<x pos="1">' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(i.YourString,' ','§§Split§§') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML))) as A(xDim);
```

--the result

```
Key AS
HR G
ProduO
 
 
a bcdefg
Some ilastttet
```

The idea in short

- I use the same approach as John Cappelletti did (XML) to create a XML where each word is living in its own element.
- Other than John, I add `pos="1"` to the first `<x>`
- Now we can use `XQuery`
- The first step is to pick 5 characters from the first word (attention: I add a blank *before* I cut 5)
- XQuery-`for` will iterate through the rest (*no `@pos`*) and append the very first character.
- The final `.value` will just get *all data* as a string.

Hint: `upper-case()` within XQuery helps to get the single characters "big"...

Comment: Eventually OP expressed 2008 and still not clear on Desired results.  Originally KeyAS then we say Key AS for example.

Answer (score 0):

first create one split string function which will also help you in other requirement.

String Split Function

```
SELECT TOP (4000)
    number = ISNULL(CONVERT(integer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))), 0)
INTO dbo.tblNumber1
FROM sys.columns AS c
CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c2


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cuq
ON dbo.tblNumber1 (n)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON);

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplitString] (
    @pString VARCHAR(8000)
    ,@pDelimiter CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH cteStart(N1) AS (
        SELECT 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t.number + 1
        FROM dbo.tblNumber1 t
        WHERE number < datalength(@pString)
            AND SUBSTRING(@pString, t.number, 1) = @pDelimiter
        )
    ,cteLen(N1, L1) AS (
        SELECT s.N1
            ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1), 0) - s.N1, 8000)
        FROM cteStart s
        )

SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY l.N1
        )
    ,Item = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l;
```

Then example,

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
(id      INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
 SomeCol VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO @YourTable
VALUES('Key Account Sales'), ('HR General'), ('Customer Support Group'), ('Production Operator');
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM @YourTable
              CROSS APPLY
         (
             SELECT ItemNumber, 
                    Item
             FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplitString](SomeCol, ' ')
         ) ca),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT *, 
         (
             SELECT LEFT(Item, 1) + ''
             FROM CTE c1
             WHERE c.id = c1.id
                   AND c1.ItemNumber > 1 FOR XML PATH('')
         ) AS [Rest]
         FROM CTE c
         WHERE itemnumber = 1)
     SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(item, 1, 5)) = 5
                THEN SUBSTRING(item, 1, 5)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(item, 1, 5) + ' ' + [Rest]
            END [Job Family]
     FROM cte1
     WHERE itemnumber = 1;
```